# Is there a list of names indexed by xprop to i3 config?

Tags: configuration, i3

XPROP returns `WM_CLASS`, and `WM_NAME` how do I target the different values returned by XPROP in i3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i3's names are a little different. For all of these if the same key is available as `_NET_` it holds precedence to the non-`_NET_` variant.
For reference

- `WM_NAME` can be matched with `title`.
- `WM_CLASS` is a two part field comma-seperated and quoted,

  - The first part is `instance`
  - The second part is `class`
- `WM_WINDOW_ROLE` is `window_role`
- `WM_WINDOW_TYPE` is `window_type`

These can all be found in the docs on [i3 configuration](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#command_criteria) **though indexed in the opposite fashion, by i3-name**.

Here is a simple script [`xprop2i3`](https://github.com/EvanCarroll/xprop2i3/blob/master/scripts/xprop2i3) which behaves like xprop except outputs i3 labels, and only the fields which i3 selectors use.