# What does _NET_ mean on X11 window properties?

Tags: x11

As a follow up to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/494169/3285), what does the `_NET_` mean in X11? From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/494168/3285) (by me) it seems i3 takes `_NET_x` to be a superior form of `x`. But unlike the definition of the non-`_NET_` props, I don't see any of them mentioned in the [Inter-Client Communication Conventions Manual (ICCM)](https://www.x.org/docs/ICCCM/icccm.pdf)?

Where is specified the difference between something like

```
_NET_WM_NAME(UTF8_STRING) = "config (~/.config/i3) - VIM"
```

and,

```
WM_NAME(STRING) = "config (~/.config/i3) - VIM"
```

I found this mention in ICCM,

> To  prevent conflicts among organizations, additional prefixes should be chosen (for example,`_DEC_WM_DECORATION_GEOMETRY`).

So this may be an additional ad-hoc prefix, but at what layer is this provided? Is this an Ubuntu thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an "Additional Window Property", it seems to be not in the ICCM/X11, but an extension called "Extended Window Manager Hints" by the "X Desktop Group" (FreeDesktop.org). The X Desktop Group uses `_NET` as their organization-prefix.

- [Application Window Properties](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/ar01s05.html)

In their Application Window Properties they're providing a UTF-8 field for the `WM_NAME`, `WM_VISIBLE_NAME`, `WM_ICON_NAME`, and `WM_VISIBLE_ICON_NAME`. The other fields provided in the organization prefix seem to provide unique information about the window such as

- type via `_NET_WM_WINDOW_TYPE`  (tooltip, dialog, combobox, menu, splash, etc)
- state via `_NET_WM_WINDOW_STATE` (hidden, focused, below, above, fullscreen, etc)
- parent window `_NET_WM_PID`
- and some composition settings `_NET_WM_BYPASS_COMPOSITOR`, `_NET_WM_OPAQUE_REGION`, `_NET_FRAME_EXTENTS`, `_NET_WM_ALLOWED_ACTIONS`
- And a few more misc things see [the docs](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/latest/ar01s05.html)

Comment: What's with the downvotes?